# Preview a view in a table view cell from selecting a row on touch

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

In my table view cell I have a UIView that shows 5 stars rating. Users can tap it to change the rating. The problem is, when users change the rating the `didSelectRow` on the table view row is triggered. What is the best way of preventing this? Is there a way to block the UIView from passing the touch events to the table view? I still want the table view cell to be tappable outside the rating view.

Answer (score 2):

1.If you are using buttons in ratting view for ratting?

if yes then **increase button size**

2.Otherwise you have to **increase cell height** for ratting view clickable.

I request you to provide **screenshot** of your tableview 
and Answer if you are using any library for ratting.

Comment: A user of my rating library https://github.com/evgenyneu/Cosmos had this problem. I've posted a question on their behalf.

Comment: Ask them whether they enable user interaction on ratting view or Not

Answer (score 0):

You could override `UIResponder`'s `next` property to break the responder chain:

```
extension CosmosView {
    open override var next: UIResponder? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621099-next.